# Why is my express router not processing requests correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For some reason my `express` router is not processing requests correctly. My `router` module is in the same directory as the `app` entry point. The `app` is located in `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// loading router
const mainRouter = require('./mainRoutes.js')

// mounting router
app.use('/', mainRouter)

app.listen(3000)
console.log('Express server running on port 3000')
```

The `router` module is located in `mainRoutes.js`:

```
const path = require('path')

const express = require('express')
const mainRouter = express.Router()

mainRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World, I\'m Node.js')
})
mainRouter.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'about.html'))
})
module.exports = mainRouter
```

When I launch the server locally with `live-server` and make the following example **request** in *chrome browser*:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/about
```

I get the following error **response**:

```
Cannot GET /about
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what the issue is?

Comment: I believe the path you are creating is //about, what I usually do is the following `app.use('/api', mainRouter)`

Comment: @YakkoMajuri the address does work, however the router isn't processing requests correctly, on the home page (address/) you'd expect the 'Hello World, I\'m Node.js'; however this is not the case and instead chrome displays the directory contents of the home directory, similar to a remote file system.

Comment: @YakkoMajuri same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The server is listening on port 3000: `app.listen(3000)`
But you're trying to access it from port 8080: http://127.0.0.1:8080/about

Try http://127.0.0.1:3000/about

Comment: when I changed it to port 3000 it refused to connect, so I changed the server to listen on 8080 which didn't work as I still have the original issue.

Comment: the issue seems to be with "live-server" , as when I run it with "node" I don't seem to have an issue. Not sure why.

Comment: Did you set the parameters according to the docs? https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server